Does Bayes’ Theorem apply in determining the probability of selecting a biased coin after flipping 4 heads?
I’m having a debate with a friend about a problem involving conditional probability and Bayesian reasoning, and I’d like some help clarifying the correct approach.
The Problem:
You are given a bag containing 8 coins: 7 are fair coins (with one head and one tail), and 1 is a biased coin (with heads on both sides). You randomly select one coin from the bag and flip it 4 times. The result is 4 heads in a row. What is the probability that you picked the biased coin, given that you observed 4 heads in a row?
My Approach (Using Bayes’ Theorem):
To solve this, I set up the problem using Bayes’ Theorem, since we have new evidence (the 4 heads) that should update our belief about which coin we selected.
By Bayes’ Theorem, the probability that we selected the biased coin given that we flipped 4 heads is:
$$P(\text{biased coin} \mid \text{4 heads}) = \frac{P(\text{4 heads} \mid \text{biased coin}) \cdot P(\text{biased coin})}{P(\text{4 heads})}$$
Where:
$$ P(\text{biased coin}) = \frac{1}{8}  $$ is the prior probability of selecting the biased coin,
$$ P(\text{4 heads} \mid \text{biased coin}) = 1$$ since the biased coin always lands heads, and
$$P(\text{4 heads})$$ is the total probability of flipping 4 heads, considering both the biased and fair coins.
We calculate $P(\text{4 heads})$ as:
$$
P(\text{4 heads}) = P(\text{4 heads} \mid \text{biased coin}) \cdot P(\text{biased coin}) + P(\text{4 heads} \mid \text{fair coin}) \cdot P(\text{fair coin})$$
Therefore, the posterior probability is:
$$
P(\text{biased coin} \mid \text{4 heads}) = \frac{1 \times \frac{1}{8}}{\frac{23}{128}} = \frac{16}{23} \approx 0.696$$
My Friend’s Argument:
My friend disagrees and claims that the probability of picking the biased coin should always be $ \frac{1}{8}$, no matter what the outcome of the coin flips were. He says that since the event (selecting the biased coin) has already happened, the 4 heads tossed do not affect the probability of having picked the biased coin. He argues that Bayes’ Theorem and conditional probability only provide the probability of future events given past events, and cannot be used for updating the probability of a past event based on future evidence. He also says that this involves frequentist reasoning.
My statistics knowledge is limited to a few machine learning courses, so can anyone explain who’s in the right here? Any help would be appreciated!

Your friend is clearly wrong.  Consider an extreme case where you toss the chosen coin $10^{10}$ times and got Heads every time.  In that case, there is no (sensible) doubt regarding the nature of the chosen coin.

@lulu Post as an answer. +1 for using the extreme case.

Your computation is fine.

The probability for future event $F$ given past event $E$, is related to the probability for past event given future event by Bayes' Rule:$$\Bbb P(F\mid E)=\dfrac{\Bbb P(F),\Bbb P(E\mid F)}{\Bbb P(E)}\\Bbb P(E\mid F)=\dfrac{\Bbb P(E),\Bbb P(F\mid E)}{\Bbb P(F)}$$ The historic timeline of events does not change the algebra; Bayesian Updating is not based on whence things may have happened.

I don't understand your friend's position.  Of course you can change your estimate of the relevant probability according to the evidence you acquire.  If you tossed it once and got $T$, that would settle the matter, right?  On the other hand, if you tossed it $10^{10}$ times and got $H$ every time...well, that too would settle the matter, at least effectively.
Your solution, via Bayes', is fine.
